# Context Manager Reverse

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I'm at an intermediate level with Python, and I've recently been playing around with Python context managers.  I wanted to invert the order in which the enter and exit are run.  So I wrote this context manager:

```
class ReversibleContextManager(object):

    def __enter__(self, *args):
        print('d')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print('g')
        return self

    def __invert__(self):
        self.__enter__, self.__exit__ = self.__exit__, self.__enter__
        return self
```

It works fine forwards:

```
with ContextManager():
    print('o')

d
o
g
```

But in reverse, we still get:

```
with ~ContextManager():
    print('a')

d
o
g
```

If we call the enter and exit functions explicitly, as expected, we get:

```
with ReversibleContextManager() as c:
    c.__enter__()
    print('o')
    c.__exit__()

d
d
o
g
g
```

BUT the order IS reversed for the instance's method!

```
with ~ReversibleContextManager() as c:
    c.__enter__()
    print('o')
    c.__exit__()

d
g
o
d
g
```

So it looks like the with statement calls using the method bound to the Class rather than the instance (is this the right terminology?).  Is this expected?

i.e.

what is called is:

```
c = ReversibleContextManager()
c.__invert__()
ReversibleContextManager.__enter__(c)
...in context...
ReversibleContextManager.__exit__(c)
```

Rather than what I expect:

```
c = ReversibleContextManager()
c.__invert__()
c.__enter__()
...in context...
c.__exit__()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So it looks like the with statement calls using the method bound to the Class rather than the instance (is this the right terminology?). Is this expected?

Absolutely. That's how Python generally looks up special methods. This is mostly so in cases like if you have a class `Foo` that implements `__str__`, `print Foo` calls `type(Foo).__str__` instead of `Foo.__str__`.

Comment: @AdamSmith: If special method lookup checked the instance first, then trying to print the `Foo` class itself would call a `__str__` method designed to stringify Foo *instances*.

Comment: Yep, I figured that out almost immediately after clicking "Add Comment." Your further edits helped a lot. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this kinda makes sense to me.  I guess I need a bit more time poking around in the more finicky parts of the language to fully appreciate why it is required though.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could create your reversed class inside the `__invert__` function and return an instance of the new class.

```
class ReversibleContextManager(object):
    def __enter__(self, *args):
        print('enter')
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print('exit')
        return self
    def __invert__(self):
        new = type("ReversibleContextManager",
                   (object,),
                   {'__enter__': self.__exit__,
                    '__exit__': self.__enter__})
        return new()

>>> with ReversibleContextManager() as f:
...     print("normal")
enter
normal
exit

>>> with ~ReversibleContextManager() as f:
...     print("reversed")
exit
reversed
enter
```

Comment: Nice work around, I came up with a few others, but this is the most elegant!

Answer (score 1):

A more verbose but pretty explicit way is to use two helper functions and just switch which one comes at enter and exit by a flag `reverse`:

```
class ReversibleContextManager(object):

    def __init__(self, reverse=False):
        self.reverse = reverse

    def _enter(self, *args):
        print('d')
        return self

    def _exit(self, *args):
        print('g')
        return self

    def __enter__(self, *args):
        if self.reverse:
            return self._exit(*args)
        return self._enter(*args)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        if self.reverse:
            return self._enter(*args)
        return self._exit(*args)

    def __invert__(self):
        self.reverse = True
        return self


>>> with ReversibleContextManager() as r:
    print('o')
d
o
g

>>> with ~ReversibleContextManager() as r:
    print('o')
g
o
d

>>> with ReversibleContextManager(reverse=True) as r:
    print('o')
g
o
d
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this was actually one of my workarounds!  It's not ideal though, as I wanted to use this as an abstract class to mix in with another context manager.  This way, you end up having to overload the `_enter` and `_exits` rather than `__enter__` and `__exit__` as you would otherwise expect.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
class ReversibleContextManager(object):

    inverted = False

    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__.inverted:
            self.__invert__()
            self.__class__.inverted = False

    def __enter__(self, *args):
        print('d')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print('g')
        return self

    def __invert__(self):
        self.__class__.inverted = True
        self.__class__.__enter__, self.__class__.__exit__ = self.__exit__, self.__enter__
        return self
```